# How to call an Action class in Struts 2 by AJAX with parameter

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I am trying to call an action class by `AJAX` with a parameter, but I can't find the right way.

I am using the following syntax from struts 2, without `AJAX` :

```
<s:url action="painel.visualizarErro.action" namespace="/errosView.jsp" var="id" />
window.location = '<s:property value="id" />?jobId=' + jobId;
```

The problem is I cannot pass `<s:property value="id" />?jobId=' + jobId` by `AJAX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax(contextPath,{
  type:'POST',
  data:{ 'actionToPerform': methodName,
         'param1': param1,
         'param2': param2
       },

  success: function(response){
  },
  error : function(response){
  }
  });
```

Comment: While this code might work, it's better to add some explanation or description of **how or why** this is a solution.

Comment: This really was helpful. I just knowed do like that:            <s:url action="painel.visualizarErro.action" namespace="/errosView.jsp" var="id" /> window.location = '<s:property value="id" />?jobId=' + jobId;

Comment: How this answers OP question?

Comment: Because I did can do what i wanted to